# Raycast wrong direction

Tags: unity, transformation, raycasting, direction

I use `Physics.Raycast` and `transform.forward` to shoot a ray in front of my gameobject, but the ray gets cast downwards instead.

```
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out var hit, range))
{
   Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
}

Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward * 50, Color.green);
```

[image: downward]    [image: downwardSceneView]

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you select your object and show us what it looks like in the scene view with the translation gizmo visible, in Pivot/Local mode? This will let us see which direction the object's forward vector (blue arrow) points, and compare it to the ray being drawn.

Comment: `transform.forward` will use the GameObject's **local** forward direction. I'm guessing you're expecting the Ray to go into the Global's forward direction.

Comment: Don't forget to put your transform gizmo in local mode, as requested. Without this, it only shows you the global axes, not the object's local axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your raycasting happens relative to your **transform**. Your transform is currently rotated so "forward" is now pointing downwards. If you want your raycasting to happens relative to the **global** space, you could can change your code to use `Vector3.forward` instead. I have also changed your hard coded `50` to `range` so that it will draw your debug ray the same distance as the actual physics ray.

```
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.forward, out var hit, range))
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
    }

    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.forward * range, Color.green);
```

If you want to visually see what the ray hits, you could change your code like this:

```
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.forward, out var hit, range))
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hit.point, Color.green);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.forward * range, Color.red);
    }
```

The last code snippet will draw a red line when it missed the target and a green line to (not through) the target when it got hit.